# Display Last Digit of Inventory Numbers in Shopify Product Page

Tags: html, shopify, slice, liquid

I am showing current variant inventory on my Shopify product pages with success. However, I want to be able to only display the last digit of the inventory as sometimes it is in the thousands or tens of thousands and these are slow-moving inventory items so its very confusing to the buyer.

I am trying to figure out how to slice (if this is even the proper mechanism) the final inventory number to the last value in the single digit.

```
<p class="variant-inventory">{{ current_variant.inventory_quantity | slice #, #}}</p>
```

I haven't quite figured out how to slice the inventory value returned to only the last digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the last digit with -1 using the slice method.

So it's simple as `{{ current_variant.inventory_quantity | slice: -1 }}`